suspend mode failure in ubuntu 24.04 (mtk_t7xx exits suspend)
Whenever I try to put my laptop to suspend mode it immediately wakes up.
It seems that ubuntu fails to suspend due to some issue related to mtk_t7xx.
Other users have this problem too
(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2020743
There was sth about modifying the kernel source code
(https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20230516080327.359825-1-kai.heng.feng@canonical.com/T/)
but I haven't yet found a solution for this problem
This is the output when i run "dmesg | grep -i suspend"
[ 3426.366001] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)  
[ 3426.422386] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)  
[ 3426.495677] mtk_t7xx 0000:57:00.0: [PM] Exiting suspend, modem in invalid state  
[ 3426.495688] mtk_t7xx 0000:57:00.0: PM: pci_pm_suspend():  
 t7xx_pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x20 [mtk_t7xx] returns -14  
[ 3426.495728] mtk_t7xx 0000:57:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -14  
[ 3426.495741] mtk_t7xx 0000:57:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -14  
[ 3426.495836] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected  
[ 3426.667978] PM: suspend exit  `


Do have swap space? free   or swapon  will tell you. Hibernation requires at least a RAM-sized, configuous swap area.
